# Prevent Input splitting in MapReduce program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I need to input files to map-reduce program.But that file should not be split and passed as whole to the map function.One option is to set issplitable as false but how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Normally isSplitable returns false when your file has .gz extension.

OR

2) You can write your own InputFormat overriding isSplitable.

OR

3) Don't try to make isSplitable return false. Instead set block size for the file to be larger than the file size:

hadoop fs -D fs.local.block.size=1000000000 -put local_name remote_location

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyBenediktov. I need to process the file in the map function so I need the name of file in map.It should be like multiple files(if present )the file name should be the key and file contents as whole should be the value and file should not be split as regular process does.

Comment: To get the file name in map call: context.getInputSplit().getPath(); To get the context of file as a single value implement WholeFileInputFormat and WholeFileRecordReader this way: https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-course/source/browse/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wholeFile/WholeFileInputFormat.java?r=3 ,  https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-course/source/browse/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wholeFile/WholeFileRecordReader.java?r=3

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to write a custom input class which extends [enter link description here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html#line.130)FileInputFormat and in this class you need to override method called isSplittable to return false.